# WinUI 3 (UWP) Dynamic Theming

Tags: resourcedictionary, winui-3, mergeddictionaries

In Xamarin Forms, Styles and Colors can be changed dynamically by loading and unloading Resource Dictionaries from the Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.  Can the same thing be done in WinUI 3?  I've looked over a lot of documentation and don't see any examples of this.  Does WinUI 3 use Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries ?

Comment: I can't find a way either, and especially since they did away with `DynamicResource`, I'm at a complete loss. It seems MS only wants Office apps to be able to do this. If anyone finds a way to actually do this I'd be very keen to hear!